# Do I need to divide my XSDs for the benefit of CXF Java code generators?

Tags: java, xml, cxf

We have a very large XSD with many elements (In XMLSpy 600 lines).
When we generate Javacode for our Webservice with the CXF plugin.
One final Java class for my Response message is 9000 lines (oeps).

I know I can split the xsd with complex types and extensions in separated xsd's files.

I would like to know the opinion of fellow Java developers.

My question is can these arise performance issues by loading these huge (large) objects in memory? or would you go for splitting this large XSD into smaller chunks?

Comment: 600 lines is not actually that large. It's very much my experience that data binding technologies are a pain when schemas become large and complex (or when they change more than once a year or so), and my own advice would be to use a different technology. But I'm sure others will disagree.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michael.

Maybe another data binding is also something to look at.
But I tend to divide my XSD but I run into the risk that the clients will have some rework with that.